# MPAndroid Chart GroupedBarChart center x-axis and ignore entries

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm making a GroupedBarChart which will have three bars. The following image is a case where only 1 bar has a value.

How can I make the x-axis values line up in the middle of grouping? It seems almost centered at first and you can see it moves to the right. It gets worse as I add values.

Also, is there a way to ignore entries that have a value of 0?

[image]